# Repetited tasks inserted into Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I have to run several times a Javascript function in order to update up than 100 forms.

So far, the following works perfectly but i have to individually call the function for each ID i want to update :

```
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("schedule_1"),"~maj_sensor_schedule(1)~");
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("schedule_2"),"~maj_sensor_schedule(2)~");
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("schedule_3"),"~maj_sensor_schedule(3)~");

. . .

setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("schedule_99"),"~maj_sensor_schedule(99)~");
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("schedule_100"),"~maj_sensor_schedule(100)~");
```

I would like to insert the function into a loop to automize the update process, tried the following but it won't work :

```
for(i = 1; i < 100+1 ; i++)
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("schedule_"+i),"~maj_sensor_schedule("+i")~");
```

Would you please tell me what is wrong ?

Many thanks

Comment: you missed a plus "+i+") also: `for (var i=1;i <= 100;i++)` is clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small error in

```
for(i = 1; i < 100+1 ; i++)
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("schedule_"+i),"~maj_sensor_schedule("+i")~");
```

Change to

```
for(i = 1; i < 100+1 ; i++)
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("schedule_"+i),"~maj_sensor_schedule("+i+")~");
```

Comment: this is a typo question. Please let it be closed as typo

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `+` in the `maj_sensor_schedule`.. Try this:

```
for(i = 1; i < 101 ; i++)
    setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("schedule_"+i),"~maj_sensor_schedule("+i+")~");
```

---

**Update**

Here you can even see a working example of the loop.. It takes the second argument and sets it as the text to each div. The loop itself works, maybe you have an error with something else in your code..

```js
function setSelectedIndex(element, value) {
  element.innerText = value;
}

for(i = 1; i < 8 ; i++)
    setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("schedule_"+i),"~maj_sensor_schedule("+i+")~");
```

```html
<div id="schedule_1"></div>
<div id="schedule_2"></div>
<div id="schedule_3"></div>
<div id="schedule_4"></div>
<div id="schedule_5"></div>
<div id="schedule_6"></div>
<div id="schedule_7"></div>
```

Comment: this is a typo question. Please let it be closed as typo

Comment: What error do you get? Because it does end up being the same as the function you ran manually..

Comment: See my example with the working  `for` loop.. You can post the rest of your code if you'd like me to help you understand where the problem actually is.. Also please open devtools and check for console errors..